# C# - Guardar respuesta xml SOAP en un DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, webservice, soap, dataset

Estoy modificando un trozo de código en el cual hago una llamada a un un web service SOAP y recibo la respuesta XML.
En una primera iteración me valía la solución que estoy utilizando, pero en futuras consultas necesitaría guardar la respuesta XML en un dataset que luego pueda recorrer para rescatar los datos que necesite.
Le he dado bastantes vueltas a la red y no encuentro como cargar mi xml en un dataset para poder recorrerlo. ¿podéis ayudarme? ¡Gracias!

Esta es la forma que estoy utilizando ahora mismo para rescatar un solo dato del XML:

`

```
            //montamos la url completa con las constantes del host y del ws
            string url_completa = Datos.Constantes.url_host + Datos.Constantes.url_ws;

            // Cuerpo de la solicitud SOAP con las variables
            string soapRequest = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:tem=""http://tempuri.org/"">
                                <soapenv:Header/>
                                    <soapenv:Body>
                                        <tem:EtiquetaTemporal>
                                            <tem:Etiqueta>" + etiqueta + @"</tem:Etiqueta>
                                            <tem:Maquina>" + maquina + @"</tem:Maquina>
                                            <tem:cantidad>" + cantidad + @"</tem:cantidad>
                                        </tem:EtiquetaTemporal>
                                    </soapenv:Body>
                                </soapenv:Envelope>";

            // Crear una solicitud HTTP POST
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_completa);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
            request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";

            // Escribir el cuerpo de la solicitud en la secuencia de solicitud
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapRequest);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // Leer y procesar la respuesta SOAP
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string soapResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

                // Crear un XmlReader para procesar la respuesta SOAP
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(soapResponse)))
                {
                    // Moverse al elemento que contiene el título del libro
                    while (xmlReader.Read())
                    {
                        //capturamos el nodo de resultado que necesitamos
                        if (xmlReader.Name == "EtiquetaTemporalResult")
                        {
                            // Leemos y mostramos el resultado del nodo
                            respuesta_ws = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }`
```

Comment: En un dataset, o en un monton de objetos? C# tiene herramientas automaticas para convertir tu xml en los objetos necesarios y luego jugar con ellos...

Comment: Tu estas consumiendo el WS a lo cavernícola. Selecciona tu proyecto en el explorador de soluciones -> click derecho -> agregar -> Referencia de servicios.., luego seleccionas `WCF Web Services` y en la URL pones la dirección del WSDL